# How To Split A Line From An Array Into Two Variables Using PHP

Tags: php

Here is the script as I am using it now:

```
<?php 
echo '<html><body>';

// Data from a flat file  
$dataArray = file('text.dat');

// Get the current page  
if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
    $currentPage = $_REQUEST['page'];
} else {
    $currentPage = 'some default value';
}

// Pagination settings  
$perPage = 3;  
$numPages = ceil(count($dataArray) / $perPage);  
if(!$currentPage || $currentPage > $numPages)  
    $currentPage = 0;  
$start = $currentPage * $perPage;  
$end = ($currentPage * $perPage) + $perPage;

// Extract ones we need  
foreach($dataArray AS $key => $val)  
{  
    if($key >= $start && $key < $end)  
        $pagedData[] = $dataArray[$key];  
}

foreach($pagedData AS $item)  
    echo '<a href="/'. $item .'/index.php">'. $item .'</a><br>';

if($currentPage > 0 && $currentPage < $numPages)  
    echo '<a href="?page=' . ($currentPage - 1) . '">« Previous page</a><br>';  
if($numPages > $currentPage && ($currentPage + 1) < $numPages)  
    echo '<a href="?page=' . ($currentPage + 1) . '" class="right">Next page »</a><br>';

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

And here is the contents of text.dat

```
Fun
Games
Toys
Sports
Fishing
Pools
Boats
```

Now, my question is, What if text.dat looked like this?:

```
Fun||http://site.com/page11.html
Games||http://site.com/page12.html
Toys||http://site.com/page13.html
Sports||http://site.com/page16.html
Fishing||http://site.com/page18.html
Pools||http://site.com/page41.html
Boats||http://site.com/page91.html
```

I would like to know what to change in the script so I can basically do this instead:

```
foreach($pagedData AS $item1 and $item2)  
    echo '<a href="'. $item2 .'">'. $item1 .'</a><br>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($pagedData AS $item) {  
    $item = explode('||', $item);
    echo '<a href="/'. $item[1] .'/index.php">'. $item[0] .'</a><br>';
}
```